# Find sum using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, sum

```
class fs {

    int lenArray;

    void check (int [ ] array) {

        lenArray = array.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < lenArray; i++)
        {
            if (search (array, i, 5, 0))
            {
                System.out.println ("We found it!!!");
                return;
            }                
        }
    }

    boolean search (int [ ] array, int i, int num, int count) {

        if (count == 2)
            if (num == 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        int j = i;

        while (j < lenArray)
        {
           search (array, j++, num - array[i], count + 1);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class findSum {
   public static void main (String [ ] args) {

       int A[ ]= {1, 2, 3, 4};

       fs obj = new fs ( );
       obj.check (A);
   }
}
```

I want to check if there are two numbers in an array that sum to 5 using recursion.

When I ran it there was no result.

Can anyone see a problem?

Comment: should this be tagged as 'homework'?

Comment: @codebox The [tag:homework] tag is obsolete and in the process of being removed.

Comment: @codebox no it is not a homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not checking what your recursive calls return.

Replace

```
search (array, j++, num - array[i], count + 1);
```

with

```
if (search (array, j++, num - array[i], count + 1))
  return true;
```

and it should work.